# How to get all Area Paths TFS API 2013

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to make a utility for working with TFS and I have a question: how to get all the possible area paths in the project?

i found some information for 2010: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx

```
   foreach (Node area in project.AreaRootNodes)
   {
          lstAreaPath.Items.Add(area.Name);

          foreach (Node item in area.ChildNodes)
          {
              lstAreaPath.Items.Add(item.Name);
          }
    }
```

but it didnt works, because i havent AreaRootNodes property in my project.
how can i get all area paths in project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the idea, Daniel

correct code:

```
var wis = (WorkItemStore)Connection.ProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var pj = wis.Projects.Cast<Project>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == projectName);
if (pj == null)
    return new List<string>();

foreach (Node area in pj.AreaRootNodes)
{
    resultList.Add(area.Path);
    resultList.AddRange(from Node item in area.ChildNodes select item.Path);
}
```

Comment: how to get default area of the project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an an assumption about the surrounding code that you didn't include, but I'm pretty sure I'm right.

Here's the assumption: You're getting your projects by iterating over an instance of the `ProjectCollection` class. This is an old, pre-generics collection, so everything in it is of the type `object`. Cast your instance of `project` to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Project`.

Ex:

```
var wis = x.GetClient<WorkItemStore>();
foreach (var project in wis.Projects.Cast<Project>())
{
   // Your code here
}
```

For what it's worth, this type of problem is trivially solvable even within the IDE. The code wouldn't compile if the property wasn't present, so you can mouseover the instance and see what type it thinks it is.

Comment: thx for the answer, but i catch exception at this moment `x.GetClient<WorkItemStore>()` **System.ArgumentException**